# How to Send via email the Entire Request in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php that sends via email all possible information about the request. Currently I'm using something like:

### Email request php:

```
<?php

$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$remoteHost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$remoteRef = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$remoteUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$yourEmailAddress = "user@mail.com";
$emailSubject = "New request from: ".$remoteIp;

$emailContent = "The URL Request was made to: $remoteUrl 
The request REFERER was: $remoteRef
The IP was $remoteIp
The User Agent was: $userAgent";

// send the message
mail($yourEmailAddress, $emailSubject, $emailContent);
?>
```

I like to add the `Entire http request` (GET OR POST) to the email been send so `$emailContent` it look like this:

```
    $emailContent = "The URL Request was made to: $remoteUrl 
    The request REFERER was: $remoteRef
    The IP was $remoteIp
    The User Agent was: $userAgent"
    The Full request was: 
    $fullrequest";
```

Looking around I found this https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40 which allows you to create file but I'm not sure on how to put it together with my PHP so it sends me an email with the request. (Creating the file is not necessary)

This PHP I like to integrate to my Email request php

```
<?php
// https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40
class DumpHTTPRequestToFile {
    public function execute($targetFile) {
        $data = sprintf(
            "%s %s %s\n\nHTTP headers:\n",
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
            $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']
        );
        foreach ($this->getHeaderList() as $name => $value) {
            $data .= $name . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }
        $data .= "\nRequest body:\n";
        file_put_contents(
            $targetFile,
            $data . file_get_contents('php://input') . "\n"
        );
        echo("Done!\n\n");
    }
    private function getHeaderList() {
        $headerList = [];
        foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
            if (preg_match('/^HTTP_/',$name)) {
                // convert HTTP_HEADER_NAME to Header-Name
                $name = strtr(substr($name,5),'_',' ');
                $name = ucwords(strtolower($name));
                $name = strtr($name,' ','-');
                // add to list
                $headerList[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $headerList;
    }
}
(new DumpHTTPRequestToFile)->execute('./dumprequest.txt');
```

Can any one help me to add `class DumpHTTPRequestToFile` to `$fullrequest`?

Comment: It's probably easier to just dump the contents of the interesting [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) in the mail, eg with print_r? It won't be pretty but it will be much easier to get all info.

Comment: Hello @fvu, Can you generate an example?

Comment: i do this a lot: `$string_to_send=print_r($_SERVER,1);`

Comment: Both the proposals made by smith and ivanivan show a practical implementation of what I proposed.

Comment: Thanks @smith just to be sure how can add `$string_to_send=print_r($_SERVER,1);` to my php?

Comment: by typing? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks @smith got it working yeah it a bit messy. I'm testing it.

Comment: @smith I did a test using a POST request with the DATA `test=test` and using `_SERVER` I did not get the email with the POST DATA `test=test`

Comment: the POST array is not in $_SERVER.

Comment: @smith Yeah, I can't see it and with https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40  does work.

Comment: I was wondering If I can add `class DumpHTTPRequestToFile` from  gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40 to my code?

Comment: if you want POST, just use `$_POST`, you want SERVER use `$_SERVER` ....

Comment: Thanks @smith but _SERVER it's to messy. I like the output like:  gist.github.com/magnetikonline/650e30e485c0f91f2f40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
<?php

$message="The following request was made:\n";

foreach($_REQUEST as $k=>$v){

$message.=$k." : ".$v."\n\n";

}

mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Replace `$_REQUEST` with the super global of your choice.  Or run similar loops across multiple superglobals (`$_SERVER`, etc) if `$_REQUEST` doesn't have all you want in it.

Comment: Nice one @ivanivan How can I integrate this to my PHP so the full request is at the end of the email?

Comment: @pancho - pretty much just like that.  You can see where I initialize/define `$message`, and you see how it is appended to in the `foreach` loop, just stick it in your code before your call to the `mail()` function.